# Hadoop YARN Web UI is not available

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I am installing on linux VM hadoop-2.7.2.
http://localhost:8042/node/node is available
http://localhost:8088/cluster  is NOT (ResourceManager)

I tried to play with files:

```
/etc/hosts
/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/sysctl.conf
/opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
```

I tried to follow [this page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) and [this page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_Single_Node).

But the `http://localhost:8088/cluster` page is still unavailable.

Could you please advise how to resolve the issue?
Thank you

Comment: The solution was found: switch the host to the IP address of VM in the yarn-site.xml:
<property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
                <value>192.168.99.98</value>
 </property>